Why does the GFLOPS/sec of a Vectorized FMADD application slow down when the input data size increases?
Why does the GFLOPS/sec of a Vectorized FMADD application slow down when the input data size increases?
I am profiling the following function for a vectorized FMADD (Godbolt link):
std::pair<double, double> fmadd_256(const float* aptr, const float* bptr, uint64_t sz) {
    constexpr size_t num_lanes = 256 / (sizeof(float) * 8);
    constexpr size_t num_loads = 1;
    __m256 c[8];
    initialize_buffer<8>(c, 0.0);
    __m256 a[2][num_loads];
    __m256 b[2][num_loads];
    initialize_buffer<1>(a[0], 1.0);
    initialize_buffer<1>(a[1], 1.0);
    initialize_buffer<1>(b[0], -1.0);
    initialize_buffer<1>(b[1], -1.0);
    load_buffer(aptr, bptr, a[0], b[0], 0);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) {
        uint64_t curr_buffer = i % 2;
        __m256* curra = a[curr_buffer];
        __m256* currb = b[curr_buffer];
        uint64_t next_buffer = (i + 1) % 2;
        __m256* nexta = a[next_buffer];
        __m256* nextb = b[next_buffer];
        uint64_t load_position = (i + 1) * num_lanes * num_loads;
        load_buffer(aptr, bptr, nexta, nextb, load_position);
        c[0] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[0]);
        c[1] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[1]);
        c[2] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[2]);
        c[3] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[3]);
        c[4] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[4]);
        c[5] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[5]);
        c[6] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[6]);
        c[7] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[7]);
    }
    double total_flops = 8 * 2 * 8 * sz;
    double res = epilogue(c);
    return {total_flops, res};
}

I am doing eight multiplication per memory load long in accordance with the roofline specifications of the test laptop (an Intel Coffe Lake CPU). When the dataset size is small, the application attains the machine's peak flops (measured in KB of the input vectors A and B), but when the data set size increases, the measured GFLOPS/Sec declines. The relationship is:
| Operation   | GFLOPS/Sec       |
|-------------|------------------|
| FMADD/12    | 127.004/s        |
| FMADD/24    | 123.528/s        |
| FMADD/32    | 124.203/s        |
| FMADD/48    | 125.133/s        |
| FMADD/56    | 125.023/s        |
| FMADD/128   | 109.202/s        |
| FMADD/256   | 91.519/s         |
| FMADD/1024  | 86.1444/s        |
| FMADD/2048  | 85.9394/s        |
| FMADD/4096  | 78.2796/s        |
| FMADD/8192  | 53.0381/s        |
| FMADD/16384 | 39.7985/s        |
| FMADD/32768 | 34.2683/s        |

Why is the throughput slowing down?
I measured the fraction of L1 cache misses with perf and found no relationship between performance and L1 cache misses. Interestingly, the fraction of cache misses is always around 50% (which seems pretty bad to me):
| KB For each Input Vector  | L1-dcache-load-misses     | GFLOPS/Sec    |
|-------------------------- |-----------------------    |------------   |
| 512                       | 50.66%                    | 99            |
| 1024                      | 50.71%                    | 96            |
| 5120                      | 50.81%                    | 70            |

Furthermore, Intel Advisors says that the test laptop has a DRAM bandwidth of 13 GB/sec. With eight multiplications per load, as I am doing, shouldn't I be able to maintain peak flop throughput?
(This is a follow up, and more specific, question of How to achieve peak flop throughput for FMA when using input data (while maintaining the required roofline compute/load ratio)?)

When you're coming close to the max memory bandwidth for a single core, latency can rise (since HW prefetch doesn't keep up) and leave less of the out-of-order exec depth for finding parallelism between loop iterations.  And you're only unrolling just barely enough to hide FMA latency so any late-arriving data leaves a bubble that can't be filled with other work from another dep chain.

@PeterCordes: Can I somehow identify this with perf? Can I measure the ratio of stalled cycles and would that make sense? Or is that a tautology and not very informative?

For more about unrolling more than the bare minimum, see Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators) for an experiment with an FP dot-product.  For perf counters for this, there are counters for load latency above various power-of-2 thresholds, so you might see that start to rise before actual throughput falls off.  Back-end stall due to the ROB or RS being full doesn't tell us much, that's somewhat obvious.

Thanks for your comment, @PeterCordes. I couldn't get the latency related measurements to work. The EventSel and UMask code are identical for various latencies. I didn't know how to use it with perf stat. Nevertheless, the fraction of mem_load_retired.l3_miss/mem_inst_retired.all_loads is increasing with data set size. Also, mem_load_retired.l1_hit are small compared to mem_load_retired.fb_hit across data set sizes. Can I infer anything from that?

I haven't tried using the events like mem_trans_retired.load_latency_gt_128 myself (with perf stat -e), but those were the ones I had in mind which exist on my Skylake.  There's also the topdown metric-group tma_mem_latency which is supposed to count cycles where DRAM latency was a bottleneck.  Or tma_dram_bound "estimates how often the CPU was stalled on accesses to external memory" for loads.  Like perf stat -M tma_dram_bound ./foo, and look for the % in the CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.REF_XCLK line.

Increasing L3 demand-misses is a pretty good sign that the HW prefetcher isn't staying ahead of the load instructions, I think.  I'm not sure what to conclude from L1 hits vs. FB hits.  The primary prefetcher is into L2 on Intel CPUs, but there is also an L1d prefetcher.
